# Nikon N75 Mirror stuck halfway

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, repair

I recently got an N75 as a gift from a friend, but when I opened it, the first thing I noticed was the mirror was stuck halfway.

I changed the batteries, I can't change the shutter speed, replaced the lense, everything I've managed to find.

I can't take it to a shop because the nearest one is 4 hours away, and is more than I'm willing to spend on a camera I've never used, but it's still a shame because it's currently my only film camera.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The camera is broken and there is no simple fix. A professional repair will cost much more than the approximate $50 cost of a working N75 camera body.

I would advise you to buy a replacement body and use the same lens, or buy one that comes with a different lens, so you can changes lenses for different shooting situations.

Comment: On the other hand, since the camera is a total write-off anyway, one may as well play with it and break it even more completely while possibly learning something useful.